How could multiple snake mouths feed a human body?
Centuries ago, a dynasty of wizards developed magical techniques to alter their own bodies, transforming themselves into various part-human, part-animals, chimera-like creatures. These wizards built a continent-spanning empire, sharing their secrets with their aristocracy and their highest ranked servants.
But the Chimerocratic Empire eventually fell. In the centuries that followed, the descendants of these chimera-people formed communities scattered across the continent. They intermarried and kept to themselves. Unfortunately, much of the magical knowledge of their ancestors was lost over time. The techniques that allowed chimera parents to control the body plan of their offspring were mostly forgotten. As a result, each new generation of chimera-people became more and more messed up.
In this context, people like the fellow bellow were born.

His body is human, but instead of a head he has a dozen snakes sprouting like garden eels. These snakes are about the size of common vipers and lack lungs or digestive systems of their own. Instead, they only have tubes that connect to the stomac and lungs of the main body.
How could this person survive while eating and breathing through what's basically a bunch of flesh straws?
I'm curious about his feeding habits. Would he even be able to eat enough to live? To do so, would his meals need to be adapted to his physiology in any way?
Note that he is part of a community used to weird body plans and he is not the first nor the last person to be born with multiple small mouths. So his parents would be able to find any information they need on how to keep him alive.
Also, you can fully ignore any problem related to the nervous system, like intelligence level or limb coordination.

Should be fine, he doesn't look malnourished in the picture, quite corpulent actually

@Kilisi This is the height of my drawing skills; it took me a few tries to make... :(

One thing important to answer the question - Is the brain centralized and located somewhere in the body, or does each "head" have its own brain? The brain is important for developing an adapted behavior. Multiple brains will make controlling body movement cumbersome.  Maybe one of the heads has the eyes so that a central brain controls all heads at the same time?

For some background prior-art, see Pierson's Puppeteers

@Escapeddentalpatient. They are psychic snakes who share a single mind magically spread accross a dozen little brains

We are not a brainstorming site. Asking us to build your critter for you is not an appropriate question to ask here. You get to decide how they eat. Perhaps there's something specific about how they eat that you cannot resolve yourself. Can you describe to us what that problem is?

@sphennings the problem is that I don't know if they can eat enough to feed a whole human body. And also il their food have to be adapted, for exemple they could feed themselves by pouring soup through a funnel in one mouth, but I'd rather find a simpler solution. Also this person was the easieast to describe, but there is many other with the same problem in this world (some with many squirrel heads and a pig body, some with frog heads, etc.) I thought it was simpler to describe the problem with just one of them in the question

Have you never seen a snake eat a mouse - or a rat? Their mouths and necks stretch like crazy things. Their jaws are adapted to hinge like some weird fidget puzzle. My lunch yesterday of Kofta Kebab, salad and fries could easily have been managed by a single head. Might not have gotten much chewing done, the stomach would have needed to cope with lumps - and it may well have taken two or three times as long to eat, but the question seems a trivial "YES". (Maybe snakes don't like chilies either.) Spaghetti Bolognese may be quicker for the ophidian (heads-down in the bowl?!?).

Given that they exist in your world we can safely assume there exists some mechanism by which they are capable of sustaining themselves. I'd challenge you to seriously consider how much of this mechanism is actually worth describing at all. Snake heads obviously eat like snakes squirrel heads eat like squirrels, frogs like frogs, etc. What purpose does establishing these details serve to you the worldbuilder? We are an opinionated question and answer site with limitations not just on topics but the type of questions asked. If you don't know make something up don't ask us to brainstorm for you.

@sphennings My purpose is to make the neighborood they live in feel more realistic and not just a one-off gag, by being able to describe how the weirdest chimeras can still manage to do mundane everyday things. I do want to understand how they can eat, drink, poop, clean themselves, and sleep even if most of it won't end up in the actual story. The part about eating through tiny throats without chewing was the one I was most unsure of

@Escapeddentalpatient. I thought snakes could do that only once every few days, and was not sure if a human body could sustain itself on unchewed food for it's entire life without too much problems. Are snake even physically able to slurp spaghetti?

We have a roast once per week, doesn't mean our mouths couldn't cope with chicken every day. "Are snake even physically able to slurp spaghetti?" - well, what does the fine-print on your artistic license say on that?

@Escapeddentalpatient. If possible, I'd prefer to keep artistic license to a minimum and have the different bodyparts of the chimera work the same as when then are attached to the correct animal. Expect when it comes to the nervous system and inteligence level, that part is completely handwaved from the start

As a reference, the caloric value of a mouse seems to indicate that an average human would need 7-10 of them per day. If you only want each head to eat twice per week or so, then you'd need 25-35 heads per body. Proper medusa-style.

the problem isn't the snake heads, it's the digestive system
Snakes eat food and survive all the time, but we need to address how they do that.
Image courtesy Have Snakes Will Travel
So all those snakes hork down a whole nest of mice... and then what? A snake's digestive system is designed to handle this.
Your hybrid person's digestive system must do the same.

Superficially, snakes have many of the same components as the human digestive system. The digestive system spans the length of a snake’s fat, rope-like body, starting with the mouth or the buccal cavity, and extending into the stomach.
Snakes usually feast on smallish prey, such as rodents, birds, lizards and occasionally other snakes. For larger prey, the snake has a “walking jaw”. The two halves of its jaw can operate separately and sort of “walk” over their large prey, swallowing it head first. The curved fangs prevent the animals from escaping, digging in deeper as the animal struggles to escape (if the animal is still alive).
The meal then makes its way down (or through?) the esophagus to the stomach.
A snake’s stomach, like many other stomachs in the animal kingdom, secretes a cocktail of acid (hydrochloric acid) and digestive enzymes to break down the food.
From the stomach, we move on to the small intestine. The snake also has a pancreas, a liver, and a gall bladder that secrete digestive enzymes into the intestine. The intestine absorbs the nutrients into the bloodstream. From the small intestine, we move to a sort of large intestine-like space.
The snake is able to digest most of the animal it eats, including the bones. The only parts that remain are hair, which is made of a resistant protein called keratin, as well as calcium from the bone. This the snake excretes in the form of pellets. (Source)

Your hybrid must do the same thing, right down to excreting the keratin/calcium pellets. Where you have some cool flexibility is that you could make those snake heads litterally snakes, meaning all the digestion occurs in the snakes and, once digested, could therafter move to a second stomach (a bit, kinda, like a cow) where the digestion is completed and nutrition gathered for the body. Or it can all happen in the snakes and the body is really just a big ambulatory thing (boring!) or all the digestion can occur in the big old body and none at all in the snakes.
But my point is that where there be snakes, there be snake digestion. That's that you need to focus on.
